# Access "Page Tab Edit URL" from the page

Tags: facebook, url, edit

I added "Page Tab Edit URL" to my application, and then added the application the my fan page.

How can I access the edit url directly from my facebook fan page?

Answer (score 10):

It's not as easy as it should be.  As perx wrote on http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=88920 ...

> Click "Edit page" button on your fan-page. Then go to "Apps" and click "Go to App" link near your app name. This link will laed you to previously set "Edit Url".

Comment: What is the page tab edit url actually for? Is this properly documented anywhere?

Comment: Unfortunately that link is now dead. Ironically because SO is FB's development forum now :D

Answer (score 6):

You can also used the `signed_request` to read whether the viewing user is a page admin and customise the content based on that. There's details of that [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/).